# Visual Studio Express 2013 add reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis

I'm trying to execute a SSIS project (dtsx package) from a visual studio 2013 express form.

I found this article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090(v=sql.110).aspx) which indicates that I must add a reference:

```
On the Project menu, click Add Reference and add a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll. Click OK.
```

There is no reference like that available.  After searching I found an article that said I must browse to this folder `(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies)` but it is not there either.

Am I going about this totally the wrong way or is this not available in VS2013 express.  The SSIS package was done in Sql Server Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it in C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS